# How to expose HTTP API as a Flink source

Tags: java, rest, http, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I would like to expose HTTP API as a Flink source in Java, so I can receive data by HTTP request, return a response to caller and pass this data to the next Flink operator.

I didn't find any documentation about it and also I would like to get an implementation example for it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use SourceFunction.

https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/f6d40bcfd89e67647d1f9cb41fa8be613d122494/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/source/SocketTextStreamFunction.java

FYI